# Saxon cant find Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/string}decode-uri()

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am using `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/string"` as namespace which should contain `decode-uri()` function. I assume that the namespace is not working. Is there a replacement for this namespace?

Comment: http://www.exslt.org/howto.html#functions

Comment: Hi Mark, from Martin i got that this  EXSLT functions is not supported by Saxon. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/functions/exslt, the commercial editions of Saxon 9 support some EXSLT functions, but not the one you want to use.

Comment: does XALAN 1.0 support this EXSLT function?

Comment: No, I don't think so, http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltStrings.html does not list that function.

Comment: thanks, but if my xslt is using these functions what changes do i need to do to get it working? or any work around.

Comment: You either need to find an XSLT processor that implements those functions or you need to check whether there is an extension function mechanism supported by your XSLT processor that allows you to implement them yourself or use an existing implementation. If your are using an XSLT 2.0 processor then of course the first check should be whether there is an implementation as an XSLT function or whether you at least could not implement it as such. After all XSLT 2.0 has `xsl:function` to allow you to add functions without needing to rely on propietary extension elements like `ms:script` or similar.

Comment: The other thing I would add is, is the function really necessary? Most interfaces that accept URIs will accept them without decoding. Indeed, the encoded form is much more likely to be accepted than the decoded form. Try creating a dummy implementation using xsl:function and see if anything breaks.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I removed decode-uri from the sample xsl and every thing is working fine. Decode-uri function was not at all needed.